# CGAL namespacing issues in the tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cgal

I am trying to make CGAL working in Visual Studio (VS) 2017 64bit on Windows 10. I have followed the installation and compilation steps outlined at [Download CGAL for Windows](https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html). I am able to compile examples into .exe files with CMake and execute them, no troubles.

However, now I would like to create an own project in VS and use the CGAL libraries. The workflow:

1. Open the solution file named `CGAL.sln` in VS.
2. Create a new project and choose to add it to the solution.
3. In this new project properties window, go to Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General and add the path `C:\dev\CGAL-4.11\include` in the Additional Include Directories option.
4. Enter the code in the created `mysample.cpp` file (copied from the [official tutorial](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html#intro_Three)):

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL\Simple_cartesian.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Segment_2 Segment_2;
```

The `include` statements are fine (I am able to pull all the header files), but the `typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;` line shows the following error:

> E0283 qualified name is not allowed

It seems as this is a namespace issues as in the CGAL tutorial code all the names are scoped in the namespace `CGAL` which is in global scope.

How do I make the tutorial code working in my environment?

Comment: Very strange. I tested [this sample](https://ideone.com/moyDKL) in VS2013 and it compiled without complaints as expected. Something broken in your CGAL? The `typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;` looks innocent. Did you try to follow the declarations? I also googled "VS2017 E0283 qualified name is not allowed" but it didn't bring any clue.

Comment: Sometimes I get very strange compiler errors reported for a file which are originated actually in another file: E.g. forgetting a closing `}` of a `namespace` in a header brings lots or errors in the next file which is processed. When I saw this the first time I was quite puzzled until I got it. Though, this would mean you left out something essential in your exposed sample code snippet...

Comment: @Scheff, thanks for posting. The sample you've posted - what are the `include` statements it should have? When you say `Did you try to follow the declarations?` what do you mean by that? Also, can you try compiling this sample code from the tutorial? I guess the code they post in here https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/Kernel_23_2points_and_segment_8cpp-example.html is not enough? Because copy pasting this gives the mentioned above error.

Comment: The sample I posted does not need any `#include`. It is compilable and runnable in ideone as well as in VS2013. (I checked both.) I tried to resemble what I assume could be similar done in CGAL. "Did you try to follow the declaration?" - I meant in VS you can use Intellisense to "go" to a declaration of an identifier (e.g. by context menu). This helps to explore the source code - in this case, to go to declaration of the CGAL types and have a closer look at them.

Comment: Thanks, will dig into the CGAL types.